# Should we cache a CKServerChangeToken in CKDatabase and CKRecordZone separately?

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord, ckrecordzone

In my app I use CloudKit and a user's private CKDatabase to store records. I do fetches for changes when the app starts as it adviced at WWDC 2016.

Firstly, I call the `fetchDatabaseChanges(database: CKDatabase, databaseTokenKey: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void)` method.
Inside this method in  `changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock` I save a CKServerChangeToken to userDefaults for a key : `ckDatabaseToken`.

I also call the `fetchZoneChanges(database: database, databaseTokenKey: databaseTokenKey, zoneIDs: changedZoneIDs, completion` in the `changesOperation.fetchDatabaseChangesCompletionBlock` of the `fetchDatabaseChanges` method.

In the `fetchZoneChanges` method there is an `operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock`. Inside this block we also need to save the value of the token to the UserDefaults. And I'm saving it to another `ckZoneToken` variable in User Defaults. So inside the `fetchZoneChanges` I get and save (from/to UserDefaults) the `ckZoneToken` value, and inside the `fetchDatabaseChanges`, I get and save (from/to UserDefaults) the `ckDatabaseToken` value .

Is it the right technique? Or it is better to use only the one variable in both `fetchDatabaseChanges` and `fetchZoneChanges` method sto store the value of `CKServerChangeToken`?

Which will be the best approach?

Swift 3, Xcode 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experimented with both ways and figured out that if we use the one changeToken in user defaults, we get a "Bad sync continuation data" error.

When I've used 2 separate values to store database changes and zone changes, I have had no errors.

So, I think that we have to cache a CKServerChangeToken both in CKDatabase and CKRecordZone separately.